# Need htaccess rule to redirect url contains specific word at the end

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am new working with htaccess. I need 301 redirect that contains "daily0.56" at the end of url. Example is:

/freeappsdownload/mobile-games/deth-rally-appid-1743daily0.56

to

freeappsdownload/mobile-games/deth-rally-appid-1743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)daily0\.56$ /$1
```

Make sure this rule is your very first rule.